Part Identification on Voxelab Printer
I'm in the process of finishing a build on a 3d printer a friend of mine tried to put together and never finished. I've got everything together, but I don't know what the part is called, what size it is (it may be a standard size?), or what brands might be a compatible fit this printer.
The part I'm looking for looks like this:

NOTE: What I have shown may not be the actual part, I just know that's what holds the tube. This is a part for a Creality printer. The printer I'm putting together is a Voxelab printer. I'll include a couple of images below.
It is the part which holds the end of the nylon (or whatever it's made out of) Bowden tube.
Here's an image of the printer itself. I believe from what it says on the screen, it's a Voxelab Aquila C2:

And here is a picture of where this little device goes in the filament extruder motor:


I believe what you are describing and showing is a Bowden tube coupler or pneumatic fitting.
An Amazon search for "bowden tube coupler" shows the same part.

If you don't know, you don't know :o) That would truly be the name I believe. The other part of my question was are these specific or generic? They look generic, but I didn't want to just jump right in if there are differences. I see there are two different sizes primarily, which one appears to be motor end (larger threaded area) and one for the hot end (smaller threaded area). Are these fairly much standard?

Yes, there are two different sizes as you mentioned. And they are fairly standard.

TY for your help :o)
